# Object doesn't support this property or method, internet explorer 8

Tags: jquery

PS : i am using internet explorer in build debugger (F12)

I am having a problem with ie 8, i keep on getting "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the execution of this script (name.size() apparently pauses a problem) although i am pretty sure that my script is 100 % correct  PART 1, i have tried every other way from length....which leads me to think that the problem might be provoced by some other portions earlier in my code. i am also having the same error on PART 2 of my code.

so to resume the two codes below create this error (Object doesn't support this property or method), one on the size,  and the other on the title tag

Any thoughts please ?

PART 1 :

```
 $('input:hidden').each(function(){
    var name ="[name='"+$(this).attr('name')+"']";
    if($(name).size()>1){
        $(this).remove();
    }
    });
```

PART 2:

```
   <title>C O C P I T -- COnsistency Catalog Parameterisation Inventory</title>
    <LINK href="formIE.css" rel=stylesheet type=text/css>
    <script type='text/JavaScript'>
```

Comment: You should use property 'length' instead of 'size()' method

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or at least post relevant HTML code?

Comment: BTW, what is PART2 of your code?

Comment: you should be able to see it now

Comment: Where should i be able to see it?

Comment: title>C O C P I T -- COnsistency Catalog Parameterisation Inventory</title>
    <LINK href="formIE.css" rel=stylesheet type=text/css>
    <script type='text/JavaScript'

Comment: This is part 2 and the debugger points that the title tag is causing the error !!

Comment: I'm talking about HTML code relevant to `$('input:hidden')` ...

Comment: Ah sorry i thought you were asking about part 2 , the input:hidden is not specific to one HTML code, it's generic to all my forms. in fact before the AJAX call i search my form for all inputs of type hidden and put them in string so nothing special here.

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery objects are array-like in that they expose the selector's matched elements like an array, why not treat it as such?

```
if( $(name).length > 1)
```

Comment: "The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead." So there you have it.

Comment: i have already pointed in my post that i have used length and size and other tricks and i still got the same issue.

Comment: Deprecated but not removed, still works in jq2.x . The problem i think come from selector returns null object

Comment: Obviously it's causing problems or unexpected behaviors seeing how it's deprecated, so I don't see a problem with using length instead

Comment: this is giving me the same issues    its not my script its something else                       $('input:hidden').each(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  if($("[name='"+name+"']").length >1){  
    $(this).remove();
  }
 });

Comment: There is no problem using length instead, it's preferred, i just said i don't think it is the issue here